# How to validate a form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, view

I am using code igniter 2.1.0 ad i trying to validate a form(though this form is found the homepage of this website),  have followed the documentation on this but does not seem to work as expected.Each time i include the   library the page re arranges itself. please some one tell me what could be wrong.beow is that portion of my page i am trying to vaidate.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<form id="signup" action="" method="GET">
    <label>
        username:<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="31"/>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        email:<input type="text" name="email" values="" size="31"/>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        password:<input name="password" type="password" value="" size="31"/>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        confirm password:<input name="passcon" type="password" value="" size="31"/>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        date of birth:<input type="date" name="dob" value="" size="31" />
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
    <br>

     <input id="button" type="submit" value="Signup" />
</form>
```

Comment: codeigniter form validation occurs in the controller, I'm only seeing a view here.  Do you have the `form_validation` being loaded in the controller?

Comment: User guide here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

First you must include the form_validation library from the controller:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Second you need to specify the restrictions:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|trim|minlength[6]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
etc..
```

Third you need to submit the form in case of every thing went correctly:

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
   // All requirement are met
}else{
   // Not all requirement are met
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use form helper instead of HTML  tags, it permits your site to be more portable in the event your URLs ever change. So it would look like this on your view :

```
  <?php
  echo form_open('controllername/form_validation');
  echo validation_errors();
  $data = array(
          'size'=> '31',
        );
  echo form_input('username',$data);
  echo form_input('email',$data);
  echo form_password('password', $data);
  echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Login', $data);
  echo form_close();
```

And then in your controller, create a method called form validation

```
public function form_validation(){
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'min_length[5]|required|');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email');// This is where you configure your rules
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');
    if ($this->form_validation->run())// If all the rules are respected, run() function return a boolean 
    {
     // Add the behavior to adopt
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as Amir and Vincent you should load library form validation, i usually load the library form validation in autoload.php.

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','form_validation');
```

i used session too for flashdata. oke may be you can try this one.

view:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flash_info'); ?>
<form id="signup" action="" method="GET">
<label>
    username:<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="31"/>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    email:<input type="text" name="email" values="" size="31"/>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    password:<input name="password" type="password" value="" size="31"/>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    confirm password:<input name="passcon" type="password" value="" size="31"/>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    date of birth:<input type="date" name="dob" value="" size="31" />
</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
<br>

 <input id="button" type="submit" value="Signup" />
</form>
```

Controller :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Fullname', 'required|xss_clean'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Place Born', 'required|xss_clean');        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Fullname','required|xss_clean|matches[passcon]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('passcon','Confirm Password', 'required|xss_clean|');
if($this->form_validate->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_info',validation_errors()); 
     redirect('your_controller');
}else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_info',validation_errors()); 
    redirect('your_controller');
    }
```